# Аналог списка (коллекции) List из Java в языке Swift

Tags: java, swift

В Java в список List можно было добавлять любые объекты. Было очень удобно создать класс с различными полями (целые числа, строки, битмапы, массивы и прочее), а потом объекты этого класс заносить в список. И можно было быстро получать доступ к любому объекту списка.

Было это удобно например при создании ленты новостей. Я с сервера получаю данные о постах. Каждый пост я заношу в новый объект, где для каждого вида информации есть своё поле, например, имя автора поста, ссылка на аватарку, текст поста и т.д. А объекты заношу в список. И при необходимости я обращаюсь к определённому объекту (посту) и получаю нужную информацию или изменяю её.

Не так давно перешёл на swift и не могу найти там альтернативу подобному интерфейсу коллекций. Подскажите есть ли он?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто получить и отобразить, используйте `Array` для таких целей:

```
var array = [NewsItem]() 
array.append(NewsItem(name, body, что-то еще))
```

В Swift только 3 типа: Array, Set и Dictionary, но они намного мощнее, чем в Java.

Answer (score 2):

То о чем вы пишете, называется модель. Создается как подкласс класса `NSObject`. Вот пример такого класса:

**List.swift**

```
import UIKit

class List: NSObject {

    let id: String?
    let username: String?
    // здесь могут быть Int, Array, Dictionary, свои классы, и т.д.     

    init (dict: [:]) {
        self.id = dict["id"]
        self.username = dict["username"]

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Используется потом так:

```
let dict = ["id":"1234", "username":"Name"]
let list = List(dict: dict)
print(list.id)
print(list.username)
```

Как вариант, можно отказаться от метода init и присводить значения напрямую (тогда let надо заменить на var).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю для задачи с лентой новостей, Вам лучше всего использовать CoreData. Создать модель, сгенерировать для нее классы и дальше создайте нужный вам объект, запрашивая его из модели с нужными параметрами. Вот хороший [урок](https://habrahabr.ru/post/303512/) по CoreData для новечка. Ну или если уж совсем хотите использовать коллекцию, то можете создать или массив с нужным вам типом данных: `let myArray = [News]()`, где `News` класс объекта, экземпляр которого, Вы хотите создать. Так же можно использовать AnyObject, для объектов любого типа, но Swift строго типизированный язык и при извлечении объекта, Вам необходимо указывать его тип. Еще как вариант можете создать словарик: `let dic = [String:AnyObject]()`, где ключ всегда строка, а значение может быть любого типа, но опять же вы должны привести значение к нужному типу, чтобы использовать его.